# Match 1st value before comma of each line from first file with second file line by line

Tags: linux, bash, loops, while-loop

My 1st file -

```
#cat 123
tom,123
jack,222
rock
google,908
mohan,323
ram,789
```

My 2nd file -

```
#cat www
vicky,tom,home
google,monk,uber
dhoom,monk,uber
ram,monk,uber
rock,monk,uber
jack,monk,uber
```

Desired output -

```
#cat  match_output.txt
tom,123,vicky,tom,home
rock,rock,monk,uber
jack,222,jack,monk,uber
google,908,google,monk,uber
ram,789,ram,monk,uber
```

For now, I'm getting only this -

```
#cat match_output.txt
rock,monk,uber
```

My Script -

```
#!/bin/bash

# because File2 is bigger, it gets the main loop.
# read each line of File2
>/var/lib/jenkins/Jack/match_output.txt
while IFS=, read -r string; do
    # read each line of File1.txt
    while IFS=, read -r string2; do
    # check match, and write if needed.
    if [[ $string == *"$string2"* ]]; then
        echo $string >> match_output.txt
        echo "wrote "$string" to match_output.txt..."
    fi
    done < /var/lib/jenkins/Jack/123
done < /var/lib/jenkins/Jack/www
```

Not able to read 1st value of 1st file before the comma of each line and match with 2nd file line by line and print the output in a new file....

Comment: Is the desired input in your question complete? Why does your desired output not contain "google,908,google,monk,uber"?

Comment: turn on debugging (`set -xv`) and re-run your script; I'm guessing you'll find `string` and `string2` do not contain what you think they contain; also, the only thing you're writing to the output file is `$string`, ie, nowhere does the code attempt to write `$string2` to the output file

Comment: why doesn't `ram,789,ram,monk,uber` show up in the expected output?

Comment: I've updated my Desired output....Sorry missed some entries earlier. @markp-fuso

Comment: By storing the first file in an associative array you'll greatly speed up the processing. bash >= 4 has it, but if your stuck to bash 3 then you can use a standard tool like `awk`. No, even your bash have associative arrays, you should go with `awk` ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the first value before the comma, you can use the `cut` command.

With the following code

```
    if [[ $string == *"$string2"* ]]; then
        echo $string >> match_output.txt
        echo "wrote "$string" to match_output.txt..."
    fi
```

you compare the complete lines. If you want to compare `$string` with only the first value (before the comma) of `$string2`, you need to adjust this comparison.

```
    string2FirstValue=`echo "$string2" |cut -d',' -f1`
    if [[ $string == *"$string2FirstValue"* ]]; then
        echo $string2,$string >> match_output.txt
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Safer and more efficient way is to use `awk`:

```sh
awk '
BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
FNR == NR {
   map[$1] = $0
   next
}
{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      if ($i in map) {
         print map[$i], $0
         next
      }
}' 123 www

tom,123,vicky,tom,home
google,908,google,monk,uber
ram,789,ram,monk,uber
rock,rock,monk,uber
jack,222,jack,monk,uber
```